# Mhchem with hydrated compounds

Tags: mhchem

I would like to get hydrated compounds with the leading number NOT subscripted, [as shown here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279596/typesetting-of-formal-addition-compounds-according-to-iupac-using-chemmacros), but using `mhchem` instead of `chemmacros`. In particular, I already tried the accepted solution to that question (add more space in front of the numbers) and it does not work.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\ce{SrCl2 \cdot 6H2O}
\ce{SrCl2 \cdot  6H2O}
\ce{SrCl2 \cdot  6 H2O}

\end{document}
```

Outputs:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `*`, as explained in “Addition compounds”, page 9 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\ce{SrCl2 * 6 H2O}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use a full stop  e.g \ce{SrCl2.6H2O}. The exception is if you want just ·3H2O, where you have to use the *.